# Enumerate COM ports with drivers

Tags: .net, serial-port

I am trying to test code for simple comms with a serial device (at the moment just a hard loopback).  The USB to serial adapter I'm using installs on COM20 by default, but disconnecting and reconnecting a few times has caused it to bind to COM21.

I would like to try and make my life a little easier and search for the port that is bound to the USB-serial driver.  On TeraTerm, I get to choose from a dropdown that shows all COM ports and drivers.  I would like to add that functionality to my code.

The `SerialPort` class only has a `GetPortNames` method that simply gives all the port names, i.e. COM1, COM2, ...,  COM21 etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please have a look at my answer here: [How to open a serial port by friendly name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937585/how-to-open-a-serial-port-by-friendly-name/2937588#2937588)

It is not exactly what you ask for, but should satisfy your demands as is, and can also be modified to do exactly what you want.