# Marshalling dynamic structures in 32 and 64 bit runtimes

Tags: c#, pinvoke, setupapi

I'm calling SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail() [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff551120%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and the SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA structure is not marshaling correctly.  The structures definition can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff552343%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  I've tried using the definition for this structure from PInvoke.net, [here](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/setupapi/SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail.html), but to no avail.

So far, when the call to the function succeeds (i.e. the marshaler doesn't throw an error), the return value is 1784 (INVALID_USER_BUFFER).  The kicker is, when this code executes from a 32-bit process on my box, all of this works just fine.  When it's run in a 64-bit process, I have this problem.

My current SetupDiGetInterfaceDetailData() signature looks like this:

```
[DllImport(@"c:\Windows\System32\SetupApi.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
[return : MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern bool SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(
    SafeHandleZeroOrMinusOneIsInvalid deviceInfoSet,
    ref SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA deviceInterfaceData,
    IntPtr deviceInterfaceDetailData,
    uint deviceInterfaceDetailDataSize,
    IntPtr requiredSize,
    IntPtr deviceInfoData);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public struct SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA
{
    public UInt32 cbSize;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 256)]
    public string DevicePath;
}
```

Currently, I am allocating memory with Marshal.AllocHGlobal() and writing/reading data from that buffer using the Marshal.* family of functions.

For reference, this is what I'm doing:

```
public string GetPathToDevice(SafeHandleZeroOrMinusOneIsInvalid hDevList,
                              SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA devIntfData)
{
    uint sizeNeeded = 0;
    // get's the size needed
    SetupApi.SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetailData(hDevList,
                                                 ref devIntfData,
                                                 IntPtr.Zero,
                                                 0,
                                                 ref sizeNeeded,
                                                 IntPtr.Zero);

    IntPtr pBuffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal((int)(sizeNeeded + 4)); // +4 for cbSize
    SetupApi.SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetailData(hDevList,
                                                 ref devIntfData,
                                                 pBuffer,
                                                 sizeNeeded,
                                                 IntPtr.Zero,
                                                 IntPtr.Zero);

    // copy bytes from unmanaged space in pBuffer to a manged byte array
    // free unmanaged memory

    return theStringParsedFromByteArray;
}
```

As I mentioned, I've tried defining a structure as outlined by PInvoke.net for SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA (see above link) and made a new PInvoke method signature to handle that.  When running from the 64-bit system, I get the same issue, i.e. the function returns 1784.  The reason seems to be that references in C#, when running in a 64-bit runtime, are 8-byte aligned (found that in another StackOverflow article).  I've tried various layouts to that structure trying to force the layout (using explicit and field offset) to a 4-byte aligned struct, but that didn't work for me either.  I had compile time problems.

I have tried using various decorations to the PInvoke method sigature parameters.  Such as, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct) to which I'm continually pairing improperly.  I'm now to the point that I need help with this.

What I really don't understand is why it's happening at all.  Even if it does work on my box when running in a 32-bit runtime, wouldn't a 64-bit runtime simply connect me to the correct 64-bit versions of the Setup API?  What's the problem?

Thanks for any help,
Andy

**Problem is solved**

The good thing is, it's solved now, the irritating thing is I don't like fixing things within an hour or two of posting here.  So, the problem was indeed that it was a 64 bit issue.  The error code from Marshal.GetLastWin32Error() was telling me the problem.  The cbSize value was incorrect.  I changed it to 8 and everything works now.

Please, someone, explain to me why the size is now 8 on 64 bits?  The structure is now above (a commenter asked me to include it).  The structure consists of two members, a single DWORD and a TCHAR[ANYSIZE_ARRAY].  ANYSIZE_ARRAY evaluates to 1, TCHAR is always a WCHAR if Unicode and a char otherwise.  A DWORD is always a 32-bit quantity (4 bytes) and a single TCHAR for Unicode is 2 bytes.  So, 4 + 2 = 6.  Why is it 8?  Is this because of byte alignment for that structure in 64-bits?  I'd really like to understand this.

At any rate, setting the cbSize member to 8 for 64 bit, and 6 for 32 bit, works and I'm able to use the structure defined above instead of the raw memory allocating/deallocating and marshaling.

Comment: Post the structures you defined in C#  You also need define the size of structure percisely.

Comment: @Ramhound Presently, the structure is just raw memory that I'm writing to individually.  The structure I've defined from PInvoke is at the link I posted.  I will edit to show it there.

Comment: Having `c:\Windows\System32\SetupApi.dll` as your DLL name is a bad idea. Hard coding that path is dangerous. Just use `setupapi.dll`.

Comment: If I were you I would not make a `SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA` struct declaration at all in the pinvoke. `ByValTStr` is just not useful here. Do it with `AllocHGlobal` and marshall the contents by hand.

Comment: @David your comment intrigues me.  I agree with you but I thought that when it comes to PInvoke, the examples on PInvoke.net are the "defacto standard" everyone should use.  Please explain to me the pitfalls of marshaling with ByValTStr.  Thanks.  I forgot to mention that, originally, I wasn't hard-coding the path to the dll.  I was simply using "SetupApi.dll".  What you see above was out of desperation and I left it to show where I was at for everyone's reference.

Comment: pinvoke.net is in fact riddled with errors. It's probably fine for mainstream APIs but you are a long way from mainstream here. This particular struct is a very odd beast. You API calls look fine but you can't ever get the pinvoke marshaller to marshal from an IntPtr to a `SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA` the way you have defined `SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA`. That's because your definition has a predetermined size for the character array, but the actual struct will have a size known only at runtime.

Comment: It's been quite a while, but to answer the question you posed in "Problem is solved" -- yes, 64-bit systems always align on 8-byte boundaries, so the 6-byte structure is padded out to 8-bytes on x64

Answer (score 0):

I also fell over this problem, because i copied the code from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2937588/1070906
which has an error in the struct definition.
Maybe you did the same mistake.

Looking at the definition of SP_DEVINFO_DATA at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff552344(v=vs.85).aspx it's last parameter is a pointer, not an uint as in the other post.

Since i changed the struct definition to:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
private struct SP_DEVINFO_DATA
{
    /// <summary>Size of the structure, in bytes.</summary>
    public uint cbSize;
    /// <summary>GUID of the device interface class.</summary>
    public Guid ClassGuid;
    /// <summary>Handle to this device instance.</summary>
    public uint DevInst;
    /// <summary>Reserved; do not use.</summary>
    public IntPtr Reserved;
}
```

it works!

Marshall.SizeOf(new SP_DEVINFO_DATA ()) returns 32 now instead of 28 and my serial ports are shown.

Comment: My problem wasn't with the definition of SP_DEVINFO_DATA but with SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA.  I believe the solution was to use David Heffernan's suggestion and simply allocate the memory needed using AllocHGlobal and do the hard work by hand.